# CPU being used instead of GPU for big batches, but GPU only for small batches in Keras GPU and Tensorflow backend

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am fine tuning a CNN from InceptionV3 on a machine with GPU (NVIDIA MX150, 2GB), with both Keras GPU (2.3.1) and Tensorflow GPU (1.14). Since there are a lot of images, I am using a generator, instead of the complete dataset, and, as such, I am using `.fit_generator()`. My problem is: if I use a batch of 32 images, Keras would instantly use my Integrated graphics unit instead of the GPU, even when I specify it to use the GPU. Then, it runs at a `Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape (...)`. If I reduce the batch size to 5, then the GPU is indeed used inmediatly and everything works fine.

Why is my GPU not used in the first place even when told to do so? I have reinstalled both Keras and Tensorflow without successfully solving this issue. I have checked on the Internet, and only found issues where GPU does not work at all. In this particular case, it works only if the batch is small. Otherwise, Keras seems to switch inmediatly to CPU instead of even trying.

Comment: How  are you determining that keras is using your integrated graphics? That would make no sense

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Two somewhat naive ways.1. I am using Jupyter Notebook and it always opens a terminal screen. There, it can be read that it is assigning  processes to the Intel integrated unit. 2. By looking at the Task Manager, every time I run it, Intel Graphics unit increases to 60-70% of utilization, whereas GPU stays at 0%.

Comment: That is not a robust way to determine CPU/GPU usage, as I said Keras/TensorFlow do support CPUs but not Integrated Graphics that are not Nvidia GPUs, so your code is not running on integrated graphics but most likely the CPU. 2 GB of RAM is not really enough for most models, so it is probably what limits you.

Comment: Okay, I get it, @MatiasValdenegro . Would that explain why it does not even try to pass information to GPU and instead directly to CPU?